# Drupal - Restricting access to users

Tags: drupal, access-control

I need to be able to add pages and then restrict these by different types of user: Anonymous, Partial and Full.

When registering, a user can enter all details to get a full registration or only half their details e.g don't need to enter address, telephone etc to gain a partial registration type.

Then when adding a page I need to be able to select whether anonymous, partial and/or full have access to it. If they don't then it still needs to show the summary of the page as a teaser but they won't have access to the main content until they have registered and signed in.

I have installed the Simple Access plugin which allows me to create groups but unsure how to implement the registration form so that if the user only enters the required fields they will become a Partial user, otherwise they will become a Full user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/Rules) module.  Create a triggered rule that runs on new user creation, then check the fields and finally assign the user a role accordingly.

Comment: I've been looking at this today and seem to be able to do it when a user is registering but not when updating their account. I'm currently using the 'account' fields e.g account:field-forename, account:field-surname etc. Does this mean I would have to have a separate rule for updating an account and use 'site:current-user:field-forename', 'site:current-user:field-surname' etc instead?

Comment: Actually, i'm pretty sure it works with 'account' as i've tested it by using the condition if 'Data value is empty', parameter - account:field-address1 AND 'Data value is empty', parameter - account:field-address2 and this seems to work. However, if I replace AND with OR it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Nothing off the top of my head, I have never had a problem like that with AND/OR in Rules.  Perhaps try using 2 different fields and trying?

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up using a hook to implement whether a user is a normal authorised user or a full user. Can someone please check the hook below is correct? Im new to Drupal so not sure if any other tables are affected when adding/deleting roles.

```
function module_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {

$dob = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_dob');
$address1 = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_address1');
$address2 = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_address2');
$address3 = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_address3');
$city = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_city');
$postcode = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_postcode');
$county = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_county');
$telephone = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_telephone');


    if(empty($dob[0]['value']) || empty($address1[0]['value']) || empty($address2[0]['value']) || empty($address3[0]['value']) || empty($city[0]['value']) || empty($postcode[0]['value']) || empty($county[0][$
    {
            $userid = $account->uid;
            //remove full role from db so user is only an authorised user
            db_query("DELETE FROM {users_roles} WHERE uid = '".$userid."' && rid = '5'");
    } else {
            $userid = $account->uid;
            //delete full role if it already exists so it doesnt go in twice
            db_query("DELETE FROM {users_roles} WHERE uid = '".$userid."' && rid = '5'");
            //insert full role
            db_query("INSERT INTO {users_roles} (rid, uid) VALUES ('5',$userid)");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You would do well to look into some of the beginning Drupal tutorials.  Roles, rules, triggers and CCK (and content_permissions) -- those are the modules/concepts you'll be looking at learning about.

They will arm you with what you need. CCK will allow for you to create specific content types, content_permissions (included in CCK) will allow for you to set visibility based on a user's role, roles will allow for you to create a new group of users, and as @Laxman13 said, rules will allow for you to set up rules to do what needs to be done (i.e. add this user to X role), and triggers will provide you with the functionality to do that.